# repeater.findcontrol not working on content page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, findcontrol, asprepeater, content-pages

I have a non content (no master) page with a repeater that performs as I want it to, but when I move the same code to a content page (with master), the findControl in a loop of RepeaterItems no longer works.

aspx:

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row" id="qrow" runat="server" data-id='<%#Eval("callQuestionID") %>' data-type='<%#Eval("callQuestionResponseType") %>' data-parent='<%#Eval("callQuestionParent") %>'>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <asp:Label ID="questonTextLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("callQuestionText") %>'></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

ItemDataBound exerp

```
Dim newRBY As New RadioButton
                newRBY.InputAttributes.Add("data-id", CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("callQuestionID"))
                newRBY.InputAttributes.Add("data-idy", CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("callQuestionID"))
                newRBY.ID = "rby"
                newRBY.Text = "Yes"
                newRBY.GroupName = "qid" & CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("callQuestionID")
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("Panel1"), Panel).Controls.Add(newRBY)
                Dim newRBN As New RadioButton
                newRBN.InputAttributes.Add("data-id", CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("callQuestionID"))
                newRBN.InputAttributes.Add("data-idn", CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("callQuestionID"))
                newRBN.ID = "rbn"
                newRBN.Text = "No"
                newRBN.GroupName = "qid" & CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("callQuestionID")
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("Panel1"), Panel).Controls.Add(newRBN)
```

Post user interaction processing:

```
For Each questionRow As RepeaterItem In questionRepeater.Items
    ...
    Dim rby As RadioButton = CType(questionRow.FindControl("rby"), RadioButton) ****** Fails Here *****
                If rby.Checked Then
                    dataAccess.callQuestionAnswerTable_Insert(callIDInteger, CInt(rby.InputAttributes("data-id")), "true")
                ElseIf CType(questionRow.FindControl("rbn"), RadioButton).Checked Then
                    dataAccess.callQuestionAnswerTable_Insert(callIDInteger, CInt(rby.InputAttributes("data-id")), "false")
                End If
```

It fails in the post user interaction processing when trying to find 'rby'. The only difference in generated HTML is that in the content page the controls ids get a MainContent_ prefix.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is located on the child page, while the Repeater is located on the Master Page itself, you need to specify the Master page with `FindControl` and locate the Repeater there.

```
Dim rpt As Repeater = CType(Master.FindControl("Repeater1"),Repeater)
```

And then

```
For Each questionRow As RepeaterItem In rpt.Items
```

(translated from C# to VB with a code translator, so it may be a little off, in C# it is `Repeater rpt = Master.FindControl("Repeater1") as Repeater;`)

Comment: Both are in the child page. The only difference in the environment is that there is a master page for the one.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. It was actually that I had the binding of the repeater in a

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
```

block and I should not have apparently.